# How to make and deploy a self-signed ClickOnce manifest with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, certificate, clickonce, self-signed

Let's get this out of the way... I :

- use Visual Studio 2012
- develop [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) applications - mostly .NET framework 3.5, some 2.0.
- use Windows 7 for development (users are also using Windows 7. There are a small number of internal users (less than 40).

I am also going to state that I am new at this and don't fully understand this process. I **do** understand the underlying concepts of encryption/hashing/keys etc., but I can't tell you why you might need a `.cer` file and not a `.pfx` file.

Now then...

We have an application that uses a certificate to sign its manifest that has worked for three (or so) years. We recently upgraded from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2012, having basically skipped Visual Studio 2010. Somewhere in that process the certificate is now invalid or corrupted.

The proposed solution: Make a new one with `makecert.exe` "just like we did last time". No sense paying for a certificate when all we need it for is our own small set of users and the small convenience of not seeing that "do you trust this publisher?" message (I think?).

When trying to publish, the exact error is:

> Cannot publish because a project failed to build.
>
> An error occurred while signing:  Failed to sign
>   bin\Release\app.publish\setup.exe.  SignTool Error: The signer's
>   certificate is not valid for signing. SignTool Error: An error
>   occurred while attempting to sign: bin\Release\app.publish\setup.exe

Now, the article *[Support Certificates In Your Applications With The .NET Framework 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163454.aspx?ppud=4#S1)* says:

> for desktop applications, you typically install certificates in the
>   user store.

So when I look at the user store (via [MMC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Management_Console) with certificate snap-in) I see:

[image]

Where the red line is is the OLD/INVALID certificate. One other one is still unexpired, with my username on it (2013-06-20).

When I go to select from the store, I see this:

[image]

[image]

And in case you are curious, the other intuitive place to put one of these looks like this:

[image]

So how do I add another one where the old/bad one is?

Here is what I have tried:

Following [these instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733813.aspx), I executed

```
makecert -n "CN=TempCA" -r -sv TempCA.pvk TempCA.cer
```

Now I have a `.pvk` file, and a `.cer` file. Then I followed the instructions in *[Pvk2Pfx (Windows Drivers)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550672%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)* and ran

```
pvk2pfx.exe -pvk TempCA.pvk -spc TempCA.cer -pfx TempCA.pfx
```

Now I have a `.pfx` file... (is this what I need?), but when trying to import to the certificate store using MMC, the password I used is supposedly wrong no matter what - even if I copy and paste it in. (It sounds like a bug in the import program... I can reproduce this.)

Trying another route, after importing the `.cer` file, it will not show up in the "select from store" window in Visual Studio, so that's useless.

I've spent a day on this and am ready to give up, but I can't. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The article *[Using Makecert to Create Certificates for Development](http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/38/using-makecert-to-create-certificates-for-development)* helped about 90% of the way...

The rest was understanding that I could do one of two things (both of these options require the certificate must be in a "trusted root" area like "Trusted Root Certification Authority", or must be signed by one that is there):

1. In Visual Studio, under the "signing" tab I could just use "Select from file" and use the `.cer` file.
2. If I just put my `.cer` file in the "personal" folder, it will appear as an option from the "select from store" button (I may need to restart the computer or Visual Studio).

Comment: How did you get around the password is incorrect issue? I am having same issue you are and I know I am putting in password correctly!

Comment: @kyleb I'm having the exact same invalid password problem too. Can you give any pointers about that?

Comment: @kyleb I'm also having the invalid password problem.  Any advice you can share?

Comment: @kyleb @julealgon @CDR12
I know it's an old problem but hopefully my answer helps. The problem is that you need to seperately create a private key for the Certificate of the client itself by using `makecert -n "CN=<CLIENTCNHERE>" -ic "Authority.cer"     -iv "<AUTHORITYPRIVATEKEY>.pvk"  -a sha1      -sky exchange      -pe     -sv "CLIENTPRIVATEKEY_GETS_CREATED.pvk"      "MYCLIENTCERT.cer"`. Now enter the new passwords and create the pfx file by referencing the newly created .pvk key file of the client.

Comment: https://github.com/3gstudent/signtools - for downloading needed tools from Windows SDK

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Watki02 is quite helpful but missing a few details.  Also, key information in that blog post should also be posted here. So...

1. Create your own root authority certificate:

   CD \path\to\whereyouwant

   makecert -n "CN=Make Up A Name" -a sha1 -r -sv MakeUpANameCertificateAuthority.pvk MakeUpANameCertificateAuthority.cer -ss MakeUpANameCertificateAuthority -sr localMachine
2. Password prompts
   You will be prompted to create a password and then submit a password.  I used the same password for both prompts
3. User certificate

   makecert -pe -n "CN=CN=Make Up A Name User" -ss MY -a sha1 -iv MakeUpANameCertificateAuthority.pvk -ic MakeUpANameCertificateAuthority.cer -sv MakeUpAName.pvk MakeUpAName.cer
4. Password prompts again
   I used the same password as above again

Make a portable file for exchange

```
pvk2pfx -pvk "MakeUpAName.pvk" -spc "MakeUpAName.cer" -pfx "MakeUpAName.pfx" -pi SamePasswordAgain
```

5. Send the file to your private clients

   "MakeUpAName.pfx"
6. Install the certificate

c:> MMC.EXE

MENU FILE -> Add / Remove Snapin

Certificates -> Add -> Computer Account -> Finish -> OK

MENU Action->All Tasks->Import

Go through the wizard

Choose *.pfx format

Choose file

Continue with default options

Comment: _Makecert_ is deprecated. To create self-signed certificates, use the Powershell Cmdlet [New-SelfSignedCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps#optional-parameters).